# How to access private class methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, class, class-method, private-methods

I have a class Initialization.

I have a method send_mail which is a class method

```
def self.send_mail
  a = user_stats
end
```

user_stats is a private method and when I try to call this method, it throws an error

```
class << self

  private

  def user_stats
    true
  end

end
```

When I tried accessing user_stats ,

```
 undefined method 'user_stats' for Initialization
```

Also tried

```
class << self

def self.send_mail
  a = user_stats
end

  private

  def user_stats
    true
  end

end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both of your approaches are correct, but in the latter you shouldn't use `self`, cause you already define method in `Initialization`'s eigenclass:

```
class Initialization
  class << self
    def send_mail
      a = user_stats
    end
    private
    def user_stats
      true
    end
  end
end
Initialization.send_mail
# => true
```

Your first approach also works for me:

```
class Initialization
  def self.send_mail
    a = user_stats
  end
  class << self
    private
    def user_stats
      true
    end
  end
end
Initialization.send_mail
# => true
```

Comment: When I do that I got the error 'private method `user_stats' called for Initialization:Class'